# Python | extracting elements from 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I am not even sure how to word my question due to me being quite new to python. The basic concept of what I want to accomplish is to be able to search for something in a 2D array and retrieve the right value as well as the values associated with that value (sorry for my bad explanation)

e.g.

`array=[[1,a,b],[2,x,d],[3,c,f]]`

if the user wants to find `2`, I want the program to retrieve `[2,x,d]` and if possible, put that into a normal (1D) array. Likewise, if the user searches for `3`, the program should retrieve `[3,c,f]`.

Thank you in advance (and if possible I want a solution that does not involve numpy)

Comment: What do you want as a result if you search for 2 and your list looks like this? `[[1,a,b],[2,x,d],[2,c,f]]`? Will you always search for the first element in these lists, or could you, say, search for `a`, too?

Comment: the first element will be unique (a number used to identify the following elements), as for the second question: no - only the first element in used when searching for the group of elements

Comment: One more question then. Will the numbers be in order and with no gaps? For example, 1, 2, 3, ..., or could you get 1, 3, 10, or even 1, 4, 2, ...?

Comment: it won't necessarily be in numerical order, it can be random. Thank you for asking but I have found a solution so a reply won't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple `for` loop, and use the built-in `in` statement:

```
def retrieve_sub_array(element):
 for sub_array in array:
  if element in sub_array:
   return sub_array
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this ?

```
def search(arr2d, value):
     for row in arr2d:
         if row[0] == value:
             return row
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
def find(value, array):
    for l in array:
        if l[0]==value:
            return l
```

or if you want to learn more :

```
array[list(zip(*array))[0].index(value)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary if that fits in your problem:

```
>>> dict={1:['a','b'],2:['x','d'],3:['c','f']}
>>> dict[2]
['x', 'd']
```

It's more effective then searching linearly for the right index in every list.